# Create Bulk Records in Asp.Net Core 2.1.0 Razor Page

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-2.1

I want to update the default scenario to insert multiple records at a time by doing following.

1. On Form Submit, data to be submitted to a List/Table and display on the same page. May be using Ajax or server-side.
2. On Final Submit post, insert all records to the DB.

My Entity

```
public class ItemAttribute
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public string UoM { get; set; }
    public decimal SaleVal { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ItemID")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

My Create Model

```
private readonly Test3.Models.Test3Context _context;
    public CreateModel(Test3.Models.Test3Context context)
    { _context = context; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        ViewData["ItemID"] = new SelectList(_context.Item, "ItemID", "ItemID");
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public ItemAttribute ItemAttribute { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        _context.ItemAttribute.Add(ItemAttribute);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

Here is Razor Page

```
<form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ItemAttribute.ItemID" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="ItemAttribute.ItemID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ItemID"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ItemAttribute.UoM" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ItemAttribute.UoM" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ItemAttribute.UoM" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="ItemAttribute.SaleVal" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="ItemAttribute.SaleVal" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ItemAttribute.SaleVal" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Here everything works for single record insertion to the DB.

Please suggest me the way to achieve this.

Comment: OR you can create HTML table(with dynamic rows), get data from user and save all the data on form post.

Comment: Yes, it is possible way. Can you post sample or such reference links.

Comment: Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPC3U.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using `Session` and `List<T>`.

1. Add one more `Input` button to handle the data to store in `Session` with `asp-page-handler="AddtoList"`
2. `OnPostAddtoList` method, load already existing session data to `List<T>` and append new record to it and save to session back.

Here is the `OnPostAddtoList()`

```
        var key = "ItemList";
        List<ItemAttribute> TempList = new List<ItemAttribute>();

        var value = HttpContext.Session.GetString(key);
        if (value != null)
        { TempList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ItemAttribute>>(value); }

        var ItemAttribute1 = new ItemAttribute { UoM = ItemAttribute.UoM, SaleVal = ItemAttribute.SaleVal};
        TempList.Add(ItemAttribute1);

        ItemAttributeList = TempList;

        HttpContext.Session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ItemAttributeList));

        return Page();
```

3. So your list is available on `.cshtml` and in `Session`. Repeat the it till your list completes.
4. On final Submit, Load your Session List to `List<T>` and do DB saving or whatever your want.

Note: Following is the code to session to work in `Asp.Net Core`

In `Startup.cs`, `Configuration` method,

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        });
```

And in `Configure` method, add `app.UseSession();` before `app.UseMvc();`

Answer (score 0):

There is no any direct way as such.

You can use library which will store entire object in client side. i.e. `Knockout` JS or `Angular` JS

and in the last post all data to server side

```
 var data = JSON.stringify({ 'values': values});

    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'yourURL',
        data: data,
        success: function () {          
            $('#result').html('successfully called.');
        },
        failure: function (response) {          
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
```

and in the controller :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> saveData(List<ItemAttribute> data)
{
        foreach(var item in data)
        {
          _context.ItemAttribute.Add(item);
        }
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide sample to store entire object in client side in JQuery.

Comment: @Ramesh I hope this help you https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-populate-a-table-with-array-jquery

Comment: Somehow i managed to make my html table dynamically. but ajax posting not working with url: 'Create'. I am using Razor Page. Is there any other way for this.

Comment: I tried 'Create', '/Create', 'Create?Handler=handler' but no luck.